# Current Location in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have done the following to get the current location. But sometimes the getAddressLine() method gives me null value. It happens very rare. But I want to solve it permanently. Can anyone give me a solution please!

```
LocationManager locationManager;
    String provider;
    Location location;

    double lat;
    double lng;

    String address;
    String city;

    // How many Geocoder should return our GPSTracker
    int geocoderMaxResults = 1;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);


        toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        statusBar = (FrameLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.statusBar);
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

 locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
        // default
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        // Initialize the location fields
        if (location != null) {
            System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
            onLocationChanged(location);

            address = getAddressLine(getActivity());
            city = getLocality(getActivity());


            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(address + ", " + city);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Impossible to connect to Geocoder !!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        lat = (double) location.getLatitude();
        lng = (double) location.getLongitude();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
        //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
        //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    /**
     * Get list of address by latitude and longitude
     * @return null or List<Address>
     */
    public List<Address> getGeocoderAddress(Context context) {
        if (location != null) {

            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.ENGLISH);

            try {
                /**
                 * Geocoder.getFromLocation - Returns an array of Addresses
                 * that are known to describe the area immediately surrounding the given latitude and longitude.
                 */
                List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, this.geocoderMaxResults);

                return addresses;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
             //   Log.e(TAG, "Impossible to connect to Geocoder", e);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Try to get AddressLine
     * @return null or addressLine
     */
    public String getAddressLine(Context context) {
        List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);

        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            String addressLine = address.getAddressLine(geocoderMaxResults);

            return addressLine;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String getLocality(Context context) {
        List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);

        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            String locality = address.getLocality();

            return locality;
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have to deal with it. Not every location has an address.

Comment: But I have a question here. Why the address comes most of the times using the same code? And sometimes it doesn't. I have tested it being in the same location again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Every location may not have an address. If you are sure that your location has an address and your Geocoder is unable to provide it, just restart your phone and try again (I find no real fix to this solution, though it happens very rare as you said). You must supply an 'else' block to perform some operations in those exceptional cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below which gets the current location of the user. This is Google's lastest API (date: January 28th 2016).

```
mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

Log.e(LOG, mLastLocation.toString());

float latitude = (float) mLastLocation.getLatitude();
float longitude = (float) mLastLocation.getLongitude();

Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);

try {
    List<Address> address = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
    Address address1 = address.get(0);
    String loc = address1.getAddressLine(0) + address1.getAddressLine(1);
    editLocationView.setText(loc);
    Log.d(LOG, address.toString());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: gets the current location of user. Its google lastest api.